The discrete PDF $p_\alpha(k) = |\binom{\alpha}{k}|$, $\alpha \in (0,1)$
For any fixed $\alpha \in (0,1)$, we can define a probability distribution on the positive integers by
\begin{align*}
 p_\alpha(k) = (-1)^{k+1}\binom{\alpha}{k} = \left|\binom{\alpha}{k}\right|,&& k=1,2,3,\ldots
\end{align*}
Here is a bit of basic information about this PDF:

The fact that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_\alpha(k)=1$ is just a rephrasing of the fact that $(1+x)^\alpha = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{k}x^k$ vanishes at $x=-1$ (this expansion is valid for $x \in [-1,1]$).
This distribution is monotone: $\alpha = p_\alpha(1)>p_\alpha(2)>p_\alpha(3)>\ldots>0$
As $\alpha \to 0^+$, the tail of the distribution $p_\alpha$ becomes "fatter". For example, as $\alpha \to 0^+$, one can show that the median of $p_\alpha$ goes to infinity. For purposes of clarification, the following plot shows $p_{0.5}$ in orange and $p_{0.25}$ in blue.

$p_{0.5}$ is shown in orange and $p_{0.25}$ is shown in
blue." />.

the mean of $p_\alpha$ is infinite for all $\alpha \in (0,1)$ i.e. $ \sum_{k=1}^\infty k p_\alpha(k)  = \infty$. This is basically a rephrasing of the fact that the derivative of $(1+x)^\alpha = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{k} x^k$ blows up as $x \to -1^+$.

My questions:

Is this a well-studied probability distribution? Where does it show up, what is it called and where to read more about it? Note it is quite hard to google for as most searches inevitably lead to information about the binomial distribution.

Is there a clean way to understand the dependence of the heaviness of the tail of $p_\alpha$ on $\alpha$ more quantitatively? At first I hoped the mean of $p_\alpha$ would be a nice function of $\alpha$ and go to infinity as $\alpha \to 0^+$, but it turns out that each $p_\alpha$ has infinite mean.



It is called the Sibuya distribution with generating function $1-(1-z)^{\alpha}.$ Just google for numerous references.

It's great to have someone at your research level here as a member.

Thanks Amir: what can I say? That I like to explain when I am able to.

The presence of unique people like you here, who voluntarily and humbly help, will grow the scientific level of the next generations with the same depth as your generation of scientists. In addition, I hope that every now and then you will raise simplified questions derived from unsolved and yet important questions here for the development of the scientific level of this site.

Thanks for providing the name of the distribution! I will read up on it when I get a chance. I'm already a little bit encouraged because one reason I got interested in this distribution is the fact that one can write $x^\alpha = \sum_{k=1}^\infty p_\alpha(k) (1-(1-x)^k)$, which sounds somewhat related to what you mention about generating functions.

This formula is correct (with $0<x<2$). What can you do with it?

@LetacGérard: To the question "what can you do with it?", maybe nothing, but here's the story. Recently I taught the matrix tree theorem: for a connected graph $G$ with $n$ vertices, the number of spanning trees is $\frac{1}{n}\det_0(L)$, where $L$ is the graph Laplacian and the zero eigenvalue is ignored in the determinant. I wondered what the number $\det_0(L)$ says about the natural diffusion process on $G$ infinitesimally generated by $L$. Though $\mathrm{tr}(L)$ has a pretty clear interpretation as an "average rate of diffusion" towards the steady state, $\det_0(L)$ seems more obscure.

In trying to interpret it, I wrote $\log\det_0(L_0)=\frac{d}{d\alpha}|_{\alpha=0} \mathrm{tr}(L^\alpha)$. I'm no PDE expert, but I've read that people in PDE sometimes think of the fractional Laplacian on Euclidean space as the generator of a sort of nonlocalized diffusion process corresponding to a statistical ensemble of particles lots of which have high velocities. It seems reasonable to think some similar interpretation could be valid for the graph Laplacian. Apparently $\alpha \to 0^+$ corresponds to temperature $\to \infty$, so this has to do with limiting behaviour of the diffusion.

Actually, it's a bit more convenient to work with $X=\frac{1}{n}L$ instead of $L$. This makes $I-X$ a stochastic matrix which helps a bit with interpretations. For example, it seems reasonable to me to think of $X_k=I-(I-X)^k$ as the infinitesimal generator of a diffusion process for which particles that decide to jump do so $k$ times. The basic point is simply that $I-X_k = (I-X)^k$. A bit more properly, for $t$ small, one has $e^{-tX_k}\approx I-tX_k = (1-t)I +t(1-X)^k$.

With this in mind, the formula $X^\alpha=\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_\alpha(k) X_k$ suggests $X^\alpha$ is indeed a certain fat "fat-tailed" statistical mixture of $X_k$ which sounds sort of like what I was hoping would happen. But why take exactly this mixture? Well, perhaps someone who understands this Sibuya distribution would have a good answer to that. I could write to you with more details if you like. I was just thinking about this for fun, but now I have to admit I am genuinely intrigued!

Thanks for the comments. Too busy to think about that stuff, but you are well equipped to do something with it.

Available on R : see here
